# C# - Reading HTTP requests with StreamReader

Tags: c#, network-programming, streamreader, tcplistener, networkstream

I am writing a TCP Client and a Server in C# which use manually written HTTP requests to communicate with each other. The trouble I have is with reading from the `Network Stream` using `StreamReader`. So far, I have tried many methods but to no avail.

The requests I get from my TCP Client are in in various forms. For updating database, the requests look like this (**CRLF** is a constant I use to denote `"\r\n"` string):

**HTTP 1.0:**

> "POST /" + name + " HTTP/1.0" + CRLF + "Content-Length: " + length +
>   CRLF + CRLF + location;

**HTTP 1.1:**

> "POST / HTTP/1.1" + CRLF + hostname + "Content-Length: " + length +
>   CRLF + CRLF + nameLocString;

The requests are of correct form and the client is sending them correctly - I have tested this on a server to which I have access that responded to them without problems.

The problems I have are with my TCP Listener code. To avoid posting the whole code, I will just include the parts of the code that are problematic (found out by debugging).

**Server code:**

```
NetworkStream socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);

string input = ReadAllLinesWithNull(sr); // reading version 1
string input = ReadAllLinesWithEndOfStream(sr);  // reading version 2
string input = ReadAllLinesWithPeek(sr);  // reading version 3
string input = sr.ReadToEnd();  // reading version 4
```

And the methods used are:

```
static string ReadAllLinesWithNull(StreamReader sr)
{
    string input;
    string nextLine;
    input = sr.ReadLine();
    while ((nextLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        input += nextLine;
    }
    sr.Close();
    return input;
}

static string ReadAllLinesWithEndOfStream(StreamReader sr)
{
    string input = "";
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        input += sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
    return input;
}

static string ReadAllLinesWithPeek(StreamReader sr)
{
    string input = "";
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        input += sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
    return input;
}
```

None of these methods for reading worked. With my connection timeouts set, I have been getting IO Exception that it took too long to read/the connection was forcibly closed. I switched off the timeouts and the Read took indefinite amounts of time.

Thanks to using `ReadLine()`s I was able to single out the place where it ultimately hangs for all versions of protocol and **found out that when there is cluster of two CRLFs (`"\r\n\r\n"`), the Stream Reader is not able to cope with this and gets stuck.**

Do you have any suggestions as on how to get around this? I need to use the version with multiple CRLFs as it is in the specification.

If you need any additional information, I will try to supply it as sson as possible.

Comment: Can you post code that “is not able to cope with this and gets stuck” because what you have posted works fine for me. Note that `ReadLine` [does not include any terminating returns or linefeeds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so what you have posted will return all the content concatenated with returns and linefeeds removed.

Comment: @DourHighArch The code I supplied is the code where it is all failing for me. I checked and the Client correctly Writes the HTTP requests mentioned to the stream and flushes them and then when I read using any of the ReadLine methods, I never get anything past the Content-Length: + length + CRLF + CRLF. It either reads indefinitely or throws Exception when I have timeout set. Thanks for the note about ReadLine. I first wanted to get it reading as simple as possible and look at correct reading later. I tested the reading with new simple server (just read and echo) and it had the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I have found a solution to my problem. Instead of using

```
static string ReadAllLinesWithPeek(StreamReader sr)
{
    string input = "";
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        input += sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
    return input;
}
```

I had to use

```
static string ReadAllLinesWithPeek(StreamReader sr)
{
    string input = "";
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        input += (char) sr.Read();
    }
    return input;
}
```

I am still not sure why reading the input by lines did not work but when reading it by char at a time, it does.

Answer (score 1):

A `NetworkStream` blocks on a `Read` operation if there is *currently* no data available and the other side has not closed that channel yet. TCP by itself has no concept of a *message* - that problem is to be solved at the HTTP level.

For HTTP you can keep reading until your data contains a `\r\n\r\n` sequence, which separates the header from the body. How to process the body depends on which headers are present:

- **[`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)** indicates that the sender will send chunks of data and will end with a 0-length chunk
- **`Content-Length`** should be present when not using chunks, you can then read exactly that many bytes of data
- **GET requests** should not have a body, you can probably assume this if the above headers are not set
- **`Connection: close`** may be used for responses, indicating that the connection will be closed after all response data is sent

As you can see, `StreamReader.ReadLine()` would work pretty well on parsing the header, and it is quite suitable for reading chunks too, but it cannot be used for reading a fixed-length body.

I don't know how realiable it would be to read from a stream previously read from by a `StreamReader` (it can probably read ahead some data to its buffer), but slapping `using` blocks around them only causes the underlying stream to be closed unless you [pick that one constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have been previously wrong, that is why I unaccepted your answer. By following it, my problem just moved further down the line. Thank you for your effort and writing the answer to my question.

Comment: I don't mind you unaccepting my answer, however previously you commented that this answer inspired you to call `StreamReader.Close()` instead of using `using` blocks - that's really not the direction I wanted to send you in. If you have questions regarding my answer, you can comment them and I'll update the answer.